# Is an entire function $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ a composition of polynomials, univariate entire functions and integrals?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $S$ be a set of entire functions $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$.

To enlarge it we can take polynomial combinations of its elements, compose them with entire functions $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and apply $\int_0^z$ as a functional.

Can every entire function $\mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ be reached from $S=\{\pi_1, \dots, \pi_n\}$ in finitely many steps?

Comment: I'm guessing the negative answer can be proved using the metic invariants from: Kolmogorov, A. N.; Tihomirov, V. M. "ε-entropy and ε-capacity of sets in functional space". *Amer. Math. Soc. Transl.* (2) **17** (1961) 277–364.  One would compute the $\varepsilon$-entropy of the set $W$ of all entire functions, and the sets $W_n$ obtained in finitely many steps as proposed, and show that the $\varepsilon$-entropy of $\bigcup_n W_n$ is too small.  But (unless these computations are already in the Russian literature from 1954--1960, or have been worked out since) this would be a substantial effort

Comment: ... Kolmogorov used this method in his 1957 solution of Hilbert's Thirteenth problem to show: an analytic function of three variables need not be representable as a superposition of analytic functions of two variables.